# Can't obtain ip-addres from my DHCP server

Tags: networking, firewall, dhcp, ip-address

I can't obtain a ip-addres from my dhcp-server and it's going trough a firewall (pfsense), The firewall(pfsense) and DHCP server are two virtual machines on my physical server(ESXI). As rules i use premit, any, any on the firewall atm. and the DHCP relay is enabled on pfsense and I also checked "Append circuit ID and agent ID to requests" and it doesn't work.

The server and client network are seperated. example: server on vlan 2 and clients on vlan 3.

topology: Client - Firewall box - DHCP server

Comment: Check with `wireshark` or `tcpdump` on both sides of the firewall if the dhcp-requests go thru.

Comment: Did you setup in dhcp scope pfsense lan IP as your gateway router of your network for that client?

Comment: Since your client and server are on different broadcast domains, have you correctly configured DHCP relay on the relevant interface of your firewall? (https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/DHCP_Relay)

Comment: found the prblem, dhcp needs to distribute it's own network before you can distribute a other network.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the **promiscuous mode** on the portgroup of your ESXi. Refer to the article [Configuring promiscuous mode on a virtual switch or portgroup](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004099)